# How is this BTC Code validating the user input?

Tags: c++

I have this CODE to take user input and validate it to increase the user BTC in User wallet.
I need some Explanation of this CODE how it works.
The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int btc_input, result_btc, btc_validation, btc_validation_1_input, btc_validation_2_input;
    result_btc = 0;
    btc_validation = 0;
    btc_validation_1_input = 0;
    btc_validation_2_input = 0;
    for (; btc_validation < 3; btc_validation++)
    {
     cout << "Enter the Value " << (btc_validation + 1) << " + " ;
     cin >> btc_input;
     cout << "Enter the Value " << (btc_validation + 1) << " + " ;
     cin >> btc_input;
     btc_validation_1_input == btc_validation + btc_input;
     cout << "Enter the Value " << (btc_validation_1_input + 1) << " + " ;
     cin >> btc_validation_2_input;
     result_btc = btc_validation_1_input + btc_validation_2_input;
     result_btc *= btc_validation_2_input;
     break;
    }
    cout << result_btc << '\n';
    cout << "Your BTC Wallet is Increased by " << result_btc << " coins " << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I see no API? Are you asking how this code works? If so make your question more specific. What part are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox oops, Fixed the title, yes the question is about Code.

Comment: That looks like nonsense to me. It asks for three values and then answers with the square of the third value. How that "validates"  anything, or is useful at all, is a mystery.

Comment: There seems to be backstory missing. To be clear, this code will not do any modification or validation of any bitcoin wallet. It simply prints numbers that are added up locally. I hope it's not a scammer trying to prove anything to you.

Comment: @Jeffrey hmm, all clear, thank you for explaining )

Comment: @molbdnilo aha, yes I also think that this is an mystery )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Code is not an API in any case but a code, and be aware with scammers. The code you have is working the same way as I will explain by editing and converting your code in a minimum form for your better understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int btc_input, result_btc, btc_validation;
    result_btc = 0;
    btc_validation = 0;
    for (; btc_validation < 3; btc_validation++)
    {
     cout << "Enter the number >> [" << btc_validation + 1 << "] " ;
     cin >> btc_input;
     result_btc += btc_input;
    }
    cout << (result_btc *= btc_input) << '\n';
    cout << "You entered " << result_btc << " numbers " << '\n';
}
```